# batch file for full screen mode in VLC player

Tags: batch, vlc-media-player

I would like to write a batch file that will open VLC in full screen mode on booting.
By full screen I mean clicking 'f' s.t VLC appears on all the screen.

**I am novice and I would appreciate if someone could write the few lines that create this batch file.**

BTW, where should I put this batch file? in the start folder?

Comment: Put the batch file where ever you want it.  I prefer putting it in the same folder as VLC and then creating a shortcut to the batch file.

Answer (score 4):

A batchfile which calls vlc as below will work:

```
vlc --fullscreen
```

Read http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

Comment: You were the real man Raoul. After so much Google search I found solution.